# How to scroll specific table horizonatally and not entire html page

Tags: html

I want to scroll a table horizontal,but on scroll the entire html page get scroll, how can we set scroll to specific div/table and not entire html page

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `table` inside a `div` and put `overflow-x:scroll` for the `div`

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
   <table style="width:300px;" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this one:

```
<div style="width: 300px; overflow-x: auto;  overflow-y: hidden;">
// your content goes here
</div>
```

see the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/8a3g2msj/